What causes geemap.extract_values_to_points() to produce such inconsistent results?
I'm trying to get the average pixel values over a period of time.
I used two methods:
(a) using .mean() to reduce ImageCollection first and then extract pixel values from the reduced image.
(b) extracting pixel values from each image in the ImageCollection first and then averaging them.
Their results are inconsistent. The results of method (b) are in line with expectations.
I am confused by this result because I expected the results of these two methods to be consistent.
Here are my code and results:
import ee
import geemap
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ee.Initialize()


ERA5_LST_monthly = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/MONTHLY_AGGR") \
                     .select('skin_temperature') \
                     .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2000,2005,'year'))
site_features = ee.FeatureCollection([
    ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(76.98, 79.49), {'id':1}),
    ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(127.4, 70.68), {'id':2})])



# (a) reduce ImageCollection and then extract pixel values
July_LST_mean = ERA5_LST_monthly.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(7,7,'month')).mean()
site_July_LST_mean = geemap.extract_values_to_points(site_features, July_LST_mean)
site_July_LST_mean_dict = geemap.ee_to_geojson(site_July_LST_mean)
site_July_LST_mean_df = pd.json_normalize(site_July_LST_mean_dict['features'])



# (b) extract pixel values monthly and then average
July_LST = ERA5_LST_monthly.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(7,7,'month'))

def extract_LST (image):
    site_LST = geemap.extract_values_to_points(site_features, image)
    def set_time (feature):
        return feature.set({'year': image.get('year'), 'month': image.get('month')})
    site_LST = site_LST.map(set_time)
    return site_LST

site_July_LST = ee.FeatureCollection(July_LST.map(extract_LST)).flatten()
site_July_LST_dict = geemap.ee_to_geojson(site_July_LST)
site_July_LST_df = pd.json_normalize(site_July_LST_dict['features'])

# (a) result
site_July_LST_mean_df


# (b) result
site_July_LST_df.groupby(['properties.id'])['properties.first'].mean().reset_index()



The key to my problem is that the .mean() reducer reprojects the image to the default projection (EPSG:4326 with the resolution of 1 degree).
Therefore,  geemap.extract_values_to_points() extracts the values of reprojected pixels, resulting in the inconsistent result described in this question.

So, if I use the .setDefaultProjection() after applying .mean(), the problem will be solved. Method (a) and (b) can get the same results.

